# Implement GOOGLEFINANCE( ) in Google Sheets using python (and read back data)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api-client, google-finance-api

On a regular Google Sheet (without using python), I have been able to use the `GOOGLEFINANCE()` formula and import stock market data (eg, to get the price at Open for NVDA stock: `GOOGLEFINANCE("NVDA", "open", <start date>, <end date>, "DAILY")` ).

With python 3 and using the `google_auth_oauthlib` and `googleapiclient` packages, I have been able to create Google Sheet (using python code) and do basic write/read values to any cell. I accomplished this by going through random videos on Youtube.

Question:

What is the syntax in python to implement a function (such as GOOGLEFINANCE() ) into a Google Sheet? Can someone share a sample python code, or documentation.

Basically, using python, I want to import historical data (for a stock) using the `GOOGLEFINANCE()` function available in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range) also with samples on how to write data to cells.

The part relevant to what you're looking for is in the "writing values" sample when running `values().update()`:

```py
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
    valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updatedCells')))
```

As you can see in the sample and the Google API [Python docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.values.html#update), the update method takes a parameter called [`valueInputOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption). You can set this to `USER_ENTERED`, so the values will be interpreted as if you entered them manually on the sheet.

This way you can just enter the formula as a string, as if you were typing it on the sheet (`"=GOOGLEFINANCE("NVDA", "open", <start date>, <end date>, "DAILY")"`), and the cell will run it as expected.

Comment: That you for your input. So just to clarify, I will set `value_input_option` to `USER_ENTERED`. But where in this code do I mention the string function for `GOOGLEFINANCE()`?   Code:   `request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()`

Comment: The function should be in the `body` parameter. You can check out the format in the docs I shared. Since you mentioned that you are able to write values using the Python API, it's essentially the same thing but setting the `USER_ENTERED` argument. I hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: if possible, please chime in on this related thread I created on a connected topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71932857/using-python-to-run-googlefinance-in-googlesheets-not-able-to-input-stock-sym