# Using Python to run GOOGLEFINANCE() in GoogleSheets: not able to input stock symbol as a string

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Using the following python code, I am succesfully able to write and execute the GOOGLEFINANCE() in Google Sheets:

```
cell_range_insert= 'B2'
values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "open", "7/6/2020","10/6/2020" , "WEEKLY")']]
body = {'values': values}

service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
    range=cell_range_insert,
    body=body
).execute()
```

Next, I tried to assign the stock symbol as a separate variable `Ticker="MSFT"` and then use it in the `GOOGLEFINANCE()` function as follows:

```
values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE(' +str(Ticker) + ', "open", "7/6/2020","10/6/2020" , "WEEKLY")']]
```

However, now the spreadsheet does not work and it does not identify string MSFT as "MSFT" (attached photo)

Question:
Can you suggest how to input the stock symbol variable (in this case Ticker) to the GOOGLEFINANCE() function so that Google Sheets treat it as a string?

[image]

Comment: First thing, you should use f string (f string my belove). Second, the `Ticker` has value `"MSFT"` so it worked right.

Comment: Please modify it to `values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(Ticker) + '", "open", "7/6/2020","10/6/2020" , "WEEKLY")']]` and test it again.

Comment: This works, thanks @Tanaike for a code sample

Comment: @Sinha Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the code as follows resolved the issue:

```
values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(Ticker) + '", "open", "7/6/2020","10/6/2020" , "WEEKLY")']]
```